# Failed opening required file?

Tags: php, laravel, require

I have a file with a simple text output.
I want to include this file in another PHP file. 
When I try to require the file with:

`<?php require_once ("info.blade.php"); ?>` I get the error:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine::main(): Failed opening required 'info.blade.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')
```

How can I include this file and/or make the output as an variable?
The files are in the same directory and I am using laravel 7.

Comment: What's your `info.blade.php` look like? It shouldn't have a basic text output

Answer (score 1):

You should use blade syntax:

```
@include('info')
```